# нет доступа к usb камере по vnc без ввода пароля с клавиатуры

Tags: ubuntu, доступ, vnc, web-камера

Использую ноутбук с десктопной ubuntu 20.04,гоняю распознавание лиц на python удаленно через tightvnc с оболочкой lxde или xfce.Проблема в доступе к usb камере.После перезагрузки она становится доступна только после ввода пароля user с клавиатуры.После удаленной перезагрузки теряю доступ к камере.

Comment: смотри логи, возможно до входа пользователя в систему тебе SELinux что-то обрубает. а сам скрипт ты где запускаешь после ребута без входа? в отдельной службе / в ssh-сеансе?

Comment: После ребута подключаюсь по vnc,скрипт запускаю с рабочего стола vnc.Rtsp поток берет нормально.На raspberry pi usb камера всегда доступна.Из вывода python:"could not open device '/dev/video0'...".Пробую по ssh через mplayer:"v4l2: unable to open '/dev/video0': Permission denied"

Comment: Запустил тот же mplayer через sudo:"SDL SetVideoMode failed: OpenGL not available
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver."

Comment: ls -l /dev/video0 что показывает? покажи. если есть группа с правом на чтение запись добавь в нее себя. или правь правила в udev.d

Comment: Так все работает,когда введешь user пароль с клавиатуры и разблокируешь экран

Comment: еще раз чтобы тебе получить доступ к устройству надо посмотреть права и события аудита в сислоге. когда ты логинишься в систему срабатывают цепочки pam возможно они настраивают контекст SELinux или меняют права на камеру. что конечно менее вероятно. проверь права или покажи вывод сюда, покажи в каких группах твой юзер. и проверь на события аудита логи.

Comment: Yakov,спасибо за участие.Заглянул в логи,там такая телега!Головы не хватает разбираться,а,все прислать не влезет сюда.Попробую рядом с этой системой ubuntu  server поставить,без gnome,только lxde.Может заработает

Comment: есть сервисы типа pastebin.com туда можно сложить логи. сюда можно ссылку кинуть.

Comment: вот syslog  и authlog при загрузке:https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1z8gXEFS9DfEET5_cqGgIjC9pesZlX1wv

Comment: в логах этих ничего конкретно на первый взгляд нет. покажи права  ls -l /dev/video0 (до и после входа в систему через GUI) и groups. попробуй в ssh выполнить  setenforce 0 (статус смотри через getenforce), если у тебя включен selinux. проверь логи apparmor, может он еще что-то запрещает.

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-apparmor-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux - как выключить аппармор.

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-selinux-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux тоже про SELinux, вообще SELinux "коварная" вещь, даже имея права рута она тебе может зарубить доступ к устройству/файлу, если правила составлены не корректно, либо в приступе паранойи в очередном релизе доступ к веб-камере ограничили только локальным сеансом, что для большинства сценариев использования десктопа оправданная мера на самом деле.

Comment: SeLinux не включен.Права на /dev/video0 root,одинаково до и после входа в Gui.В syslog единственное что появляется после попытки доступа к камере: Oct 14 13:23:39 evg xdg-desktop-por[1877]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list

Comment: evg@evg:~$  ls -l /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Oct 14 13:40 /dev/video0

Comment: м может у тебя проблема не с доступом к камере? а в коде? для теста попробуй поставить motion, отредактируй файл /etc/motion/motion.conf, daemon_mode on, stream_localhost off. у тебя на порту 8081 после запуска службы должен отображаться поток с камеры. если после ребута у тебя без входа будет моушен работать, то это явно не косяк с правами.

Comment: ls -l /dev/video0 crw-rw----+ - плюс на конце значит, что включены расширенные права посмотри еще, что у тебя в выводе getfacl /dev/video0

Comment: все,вопрос решен!А еще чайник в linux.Стал читать как открыть serial port и понял что надо добавить себя в группу .Хотя вы ,Яков,об этом писали.Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 0):

надо было добавить пользователя в группу video:   sudo usermod -a -G video USER.Все заработало.